How can turn this sumif into an arrayformula in Google Sheets?
I currently for this one working, which gives a balance per lot as per the total qty demanded by a client ABC of a certain product, but how can I turn this into an arrayformula or query instead?
=IF(C3="";"";IF(SUMIFS(E$3:E3;A$3:A3;A3;B$3:B3;B3)-C3<0;0;sumifs(E$3:E3;A$3:A3;A3;B$3:B3;B3)-C3))
Here is the file, if you want to jump in!
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1gh5w0czg2JuoA3i5wPu8_eOpC4Q4TXIRhmUrg53nKMU/edit?usp=sharing

Note that we prefer a technical style of writing here. We gently discourage greetings, hope-you-can-helps, thanks, advance thanks, notes of appreciation, regards, kind regards, signatures, please-can-you-helps, chatty material and abbreviated txtspk, pleading, how long you've been stuck, voting advice, meta commentary, etc. Just explain your problem, and show what you've tried, what you expected, and what actually happened.


You may try:
=map(A3:A;B3:B;C3:C;E3:E;lambda(Σ;Λ;Γ;Ξ;if(Σ="";;max(0;sumifs(E3:Ξ;A3:Σ;Σ;B3:Λ;Λ)-Γ))))



Would this mean that if I want to add column D to make the resulting value more granular on lot basis, I would include D3:D to the beginning of the formula?

yeah you need to include both the column range D3:D and its unique lambda identifier
